# WCF validations and fault exceptions

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this method in my wcf service.

```
public int GetUserIdBySearch(string facebookId)
{
    IUserRepository _user = new UserRepository();
    return _user.GetUserIdBySearch(facebookId);
}
```

There can be many problems with it - such as:
If the facebookId is null. //Should I check whether the facebookId is not null?

Or If there is already user with the same facebookId (it's unique) - Therefore, I should try catch it, but what's the best way to catch it easily?

Thanks !!!

Comment: obviously for null values, you need to put the condition and you can do it using string.IsNullOrEmpty(facebookId). So pass the value only for !string.IsNullOrEmpty(facebookId) and the id is going to be unique, so i dont think it is required to check and you should always put try and catch where ever you find the exceptions may come like database operations, type casting etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF will send exception info to client so you don't have to check for null BUT it won't hurt if you use some standard defensive programing: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming

Comment: Is it the Exception exception? Or I can catch it with another exception?

Comment: It's the same exception as one on server. http://www.olegsych.com/2008/07/simplifying-wcf-using-exceptions-as-faults/